# angular cli structure vs expressjs structure

Tags: javascript, angular, express, mean-stack

I'm working with mean stack technology and the template I'm working with has a specific structure! It's made by the "ng new myproject " command but I don't know how to "rebuild it" to have the same structure as the express js structure 
[angular cli structure vs express js structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1shTH.png)

Answer (score 0):

With in the GUI of most modern computers there are tools that allow for the moving of files and directories with hardware storage volumes. Features such as `cut` and `paste` allow for the efficient moving of directories and files.

If one wishes to make his AngularJs project have an similar file structure to ones express project, one can use cut and paste to move folders about until all required changes have been made.